# Weka output of attribute selection

Tags: weka

I'm using weka to select attributes from my dataset, but I don't understand one thing: for example, I have this output after attributes selection with InfoGainAttributeEval + Ranker

```
Ranked attributes:
 0.354       1 attr12
 0.333      46 attr4
 0.316      75 attr7
 0.304      96 attr1
```

Well, I know the first value is the information gain, but what does it means "1 attr12"? What's that number "1"?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! "1 attr12" is the first attribute, named "attr12". So, the "1" is the index of the attribute.. 46 is the index of the attribute "attr4", and so on..